# Not including rational number in inequality

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, rational-numbers

If you have a linear inequality like $x < 7$ where $x$ belongs to rational numbers. Then on graphing it on a number line, a unfilled circle is used to denote that $7$ is not included.

But that means that $x = 6.99999\dots$ at max but $7$ is not included.

$0.99999\dots = 1$ (sources - [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...)) and therefore, $6.99999\dots = 7$.

So although you are not including $7$ in the solution set of inequality, $7$ is still a solution.

How is that possible? Am I going wrong somewhere?

Comment: You're assuming that $6.\bar 9<7$, which is false.

Comment: Or, alternatively, you're assuming that the solution set has a maximum element.

Comment: x < 7 includes 6.9¯ right?

Comment: There is no maximum value in the "half-open" range $[0,7)$, whether this range is in $\mathbb{Q}$ or in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: No.  The set of all $x$ satisfying $x<7$ does **not** include $6.\bar 9$ because $6.\bar 9$ is not less than $7$.